# Base64 from URL with $_GET and convert to image file

Tags: php, base64

I need to receive a base64 from url using $_GET and convert to an image ...how can I do this?

Comment: there are plenty of replies telling you how to output an base64 image, and, what you are trying to do is really nasty xD find a workaround

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing the below mentioned code snippet
 Suppose the paramter with name "image_data" is being passed into querystring

```
       <?php
           $image_file_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Scripts/images/img.jpg';
           $content=base64_decode($_GET['image_data']); 
            if(!empty($content))
            {
               file_put_contents($image_file_path);
            } 
       ?>
```